# Get-ChildItem refresh/update

Tags: powershell

Pretty new to Powershell and hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Im trying to figure out if there is a cleaner way to accomplish what I have below?  Is there a way to refresh to contents of Get-ChildItem once I have made some changes to the files which are returned during the first Get-ChildItem call (stored in $items variable)?

During the first foreach statement I am creating a log signature for all the files that are returned.   Once that is done, what I need to do is; get a listing once again (because the item in the path have changed), the second Get-ChildItem will include both the files that were found during the first Get-ChildItem call and also all the logFiles that were generated when the first foreach statement called the generate-LogFile function.  So my question, is there a way to update the listing without having to call get-chilItem twice, as well as use two foreach statements?

Thanks for all the help!

--------------This is what I changed the code based on recommendation--------------

```
$dataStorePath = "C:\Process"

function print-All($file)
{
    Write-Host "PrintALL filename:"  $file.FullName #Only prints when print-All($item) is called 
}

function generate-LogFile($file)
{
    $logName = $file.FullName + ".log"
    $logFilehandle = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $logName
    $logFilehandle.Writeline($logName)
    $logFilehandle.Close()
    return $logName
}

$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $dataStorePath

foreach ($item in $items)
{
    $log = generate-LogFile($item) #Contains full path C:\Process\$fileName.log
    print-All($item) 
    print-All($log) #When this goes to the function, nothing prints when using $file.FullName in the print-All function
}
```

---------Output--------------

For testing I have two files in C:\Process: 
fileA.txt & fileB.txt

I will create two additional files 
fileA.txt.log & fileB.txt.log

Eventually I need to do something with all four files. I created a print-All Function where I would process all four files.  Below is the current ouput.  As can be seen, I only get output for the two original files found, not the two additional created (get blank lines when calling the print-All($log)).  I need to able to use fullpath property provided by Get-ChildItem, thus using FullName

```
PrintALL filename: fileA.txt
PrintALL filename:
PrintALL filename: fileB.txt
PrintALL filename:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you are asking, by can have `generate-LogFile` return the created log file, then just call `generateRequestData` on both your file and the log file? Something like this:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $dataStorePath
foreach ($file in $items)
{
    $logFile = generate-LogFile $file 
    generateRequestData $file
    generateRequestData $logFile
}
```

**Edit:**

In your added sample, you are returning a string from `generate-LogFile`. .NET strings don't have a `FullName` property, so nothing gets printed in `print-All`. To get the `FileInfo` object that you want, use the `get-item` commandlet:

```
return Get-Item $logName
```

Also, in this example, you don't need to use a `StreamWriter` to write to the file, you could use the native powershell `Out-File` commandlet:

```
function generate-LogFile($file)
{
    $logName = $file.FullName + ".log"
    $logName | Out-File $logName
    return Get-Item $logName
}
```

Comment: No, for example; when I do the first Get-Childitem I only have 3 files, then when I run through the first foreach statement the function will generate 1 file for each file found.  So after the first foreach loop I will have 6 files.  Now what I want to do is process all 6 files, but the problem is, I have to call get-childitem once again because the original listing only had 3 files and does not account for the 3 new files created.  So I was wondering what the best way to approach that is.

Comment: @user1048209 so you have to wait until all the log files are generated before you can call generateRequestData on any of them?

Comment: Not necessarily, the problem I run into when using your code above is, I am not able to use the path overloads (if that's what they are called with using the $logFile variable.

Comment: Problem I run into using the code above, which would otherwise be the solution I am looking for; get the following error "New-Object : Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type System.IO.StreamReader." I think it's because I am using the properties of a file in that function. For example I call $toProcess = $file.fullname to get the full path of the file. The problem is that I am not able to use file properties with the data returned from generate-LogFile Function which are eventually stored in $logFile = generate-LogFile $file so i end up with the error above

Comment: @user1048209 See my updates that should get your posted sample working.